# Setting "view as" adjusts frame sizes in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, xcode10

I'm using xCode10.1 do develop an app in Swift 4.2.

While testing in the simulator I've inadvertently changed the "view as" device in xCode (see screenshot).

[image: view-as selection]

This adds a device-id tag, as expected (e.g., ), but also changes the widths of every single one of my frames in storyboard, resulting in a diff that looks like:

```
- <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
+ <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>

- <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="600" height="120"/>
+ <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="120"/>

- <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="120"/>
+ <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="120"/>
```

Is this expected behaviour? And if so, can I prevent it?

Comment: This is an expected behaviour. You either roll-back the changes or select the device that was previously selected. This feature is a means to make sure that your layout is working as intended in any device/orientation, all inside IB (it doesn't actually change something in your project - just the 'simulated' device in Interface Builder).

Comment: @Alladinian but it *does* appear to change things in the project. For example, in a cell in a tableview, the value of `self.contentView.frame.width` when called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` appears to be the value of the width of the frame set by xCode in response to the "view as" setting. Is that also expected?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` asks you (the datasource) to create and return a cell for display; now, the cell is instantiated via the archived cell in your storyboard (and that's why it holds whatever values are set there). By using autolayout, that should not worry you because the system will eventually layout the cells when the tableview resolves its own position & size. You're right, my statement is not _entirely_ correct, so the simulated sizes you set in IB serve as 'placeholder' values for the archived views. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: @Alladinian It does! Thanks very much. I'm happy to accept that as the answer. I have followup on the implications of this but I think they're out of the scope of the question as posted.